Apex Sharing Rule for Financial Accounts not working
I need this apex sharing rule to fire when an Account Team Member is inserted, updated, or deleted. Account Team Members need access to the related Financial Accounts if they are a team member, and if they are removed, they need to lose access to the related financial account.
I created a checkbox field on the account team member to update existing members to fire the trigger and it's not working in prod. My test class passed, but looking at it now, I think there is an error in the assertion and it's actually creating duplicate share rows, but I can't tell for sure as it's not firing at all and granting access to the FA.
Can someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong/missing here?
apex class:
public class AccountTeamManager {
    // Static variable to prevent recursion
    private static Boolean isRunning = false;

    public static void manageAccountTeam(List<Account> accounts, Set<Id> newTeamMemberUserIds) {
        if (isRunning) return;  // Prevent recursion
        isRunning = true;

        System.debug('Start: manageAccountTeam method');
        System.debug('New Account Team Member User IDs: ' + newTeamMemberUserIds);

        // Fetch related Financial Accounts for the given accounts
        List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__c> relatedFinancialAccounts = [
            SELECT Id, FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c, Name
            FROM FinServ__FinancialAccount__c
            WHERE FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c IN :accounts
        ];
        System.debug('Related Financial Accounts fetched: ' + relatedFinancialAccounts);

        List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share> sharesToRemove = new List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share>();
        List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share> sharesToInsert = new List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share>();

        // Iterate over Financial Accounts and User IDs
        for (FinServ__FinancialAccount__c finAcc : relatedFinancialAccounts) {
            for (Id userId : newTeamMemberUserIds) {
                if (finAcc.Id != null && userId != null) {
                    // Query for existing share records
                    List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share> existingShares = [
                        SELECT Id, AccessLevel
                        FROM FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share
                        WHERE ParentId = :finAcc.Id AND UserOrGroupId = :userId
                    ];

                    // If the share exists, add it to the removal list
                    if (!existingShares.isEmpty()) {
                        sharesToRemove.add(existingShares[0]);
                    }

                    // Insert a new share record if it doesn't already exist (prevent duplicates)
                    FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share insertShare = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share();
                    insertShare.ParentId = finAcc.Id;
                    insertShare.UserOrGroupId = userId;
                    insertShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';  // Ensure 'Edit' is explicitly set
                    sharesToInsert.add(insertShare);
                }
            }
        }

        // Insert shares if necessary
        if (!sharesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                System.debug('Inserting new FinancialAccountShare records: ' + sharesToInsert);
                insert sharesToInsert;
                System.debug('FinancialAccountShare records inserted successfully: '+sharesToInsert.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error inserting FinancialAccountShare records: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('No FinancialAccountShare records to insert.');
        }

        // Remove shares if necessary (those users should no longer have access)
        if (!sharesToRemove.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                System.debug('Deleting FinancialAccountShare records: ' + sharesToRemove);
                delete sharesToRemove;
                System.debug('FinancialAccountShare records removed successfully: '+sharesToRemove.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error deleting FinancialAccountShare records: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('No FinancialAccountShare records to remove.');
        }

        System.debug('End: manageAccountTeam method');
        isRunning = false;  // Reset the flag to allow the method to run again
    }
}

test class:
@isTest
private class AccountTeamManagerTest {
    @TestSetup
    static void setup() {
        // Select an Advisor profile dynamically
        Profile advisorProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Advisor' LIMIT 1];
        
        // Create test users
        User u1 = new User(
            ProfileId = advisorProfile.Id,
            LastName = 'TestUser1',
            Email = 'testuser1@example.com',
            Username = 'testuser1_' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '@example.com',
            Alias = 'test1',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        insert u1;
        
        User u2 = new User(
            ProfileId = advisorProfile.Id,
            LastName = 'TestUser2',
            Email = 'testuser2@example.com',
            Username = 'testuser2_' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '@example.com',
            Alias = 'test2',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        insert u2;
        
        // Create a test Account
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert acc;
        
        // Create Financial Accounts linked to the Account
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__c fa1 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__c(
            Name = 'Financial Account 1',
            FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = acc.Id
        );
        insert fa1;
        
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__c fa2 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__c(
            Name = 'Financial Account 2',
            FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = acc.Id
        );
        insert fa2;
        
        // Create Account Team Member records for both users
        AccountTeamMember teamMember1 = new AccountTeamMember(
            AccountId = acc.Id,
            UserId = u1.Id,
            TeamMemberRole = 'Advisor'
        );
        insert teamMember1;
        
        AccountTeamMember teamMember2 = new AccountTeamMember(
            AccountId = acc.Id,
            UserId = u2.Id,
            TeamMemberRole = 'Advisor'
        );
        insert teamMember2;
        
        // Create Financial Account Shares for the test users and accounts
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share share1 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share(
            ParentId = fa1.Id,
            UserOrGroupId = u1.Id,
            AccessLevel = 'Edit'
        );
        insert share1;
        
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share share2 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share(
            ParentId = fa2.Id,
            UserOrGroupId = u1.Id,
            AccessLevel = 'Edit'
        );
        insert share2;
        
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share share3 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share(
            ParentId = fa1.Id,
            UserOrGroupId = u2.Id,
            AccessLevel = 'Edit'
        );
        insert share3;
        
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share share4 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share(
            ParentId = fa2.Id,
            UserOrGroupId = u2.Id,
            AccessLevel = 'Edit'
        );
        insert share4;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testRemoveTeamMember() {
        // Fetch the test data created in @TestSetup
        User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE LastName = 'TestUser1' LIMIT 1];
        User u2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE LastName = 'TestUser2' LIMIT 1];
        Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];
        
        // Ensure there are 4 share records before removing any team member
        List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share> shares = [
            SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, ParentId 
            FROM FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share 
            WHERE UserOrGroupId IN :new Set<Id>{u1.Id, u2.Id}
        ];
        
        // Before removal, there should be 4 share records (2 for each user)
        System.assertEquals(4, shares.size(), 'There should be 4 share records before deletion.');
        
        // Simulate removing one team member (u2)
        Set<Id> newUserIds = new Set<Id>{u1.Id}; // Removing u2

        Test.startTest();
        AccountTeamManager.manageAccountTeam(new List<Account>{acc}, newUserIds);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify the results: One share record for u2 should be removed
        shares = [
            SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, ParentId 
            FROM FinServ__FinancialAccount__Share 
            WHERE UserOrGroupId = :u2.Id
        ];
        
        // After deletion, there should be 2 share records for u2
        System.assertEquals(2, shares.size(), 'There should be no share records for u2 after removal.');
        
        // Additional Debugging: Output share records for u1 and u2
        System.debug('Share records for u1: ' + shares);
    }
}

trigger:
trigger AccountTeamMemberTrigger on AccountTeamMember (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> newTeamMemberUserIds = new Set<Id>();

        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            for (AccountTeamMember teamMember : Trigger.new) {
                if (teamMember.AccountId != null && teamMember.UserId != null) {
                    accountIds.add(teamMember.AccountId);
                    newTeamMemberUserIds.add(teamMember.UserId);
                }
            }
        }

        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            for (AccountTeamMember teamMember : Trigger.old) {
                if (teamMember.AccountId != null && teamMember.UserId != null) {
                    accountIds.add(teamMember.AccountId);
                }
            }
        }

        // Fetch Accounts related to the Account IDs from the trigger
        List<Account> relatedAccounts = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN :accountIds
        ];

        // Call the AccountTeamManager to handle the changes
        AccountTeamManager.manageAccountTeam(relatedAccounts, newTeamMemberUserIds);
    }
}


My test class passed, but looking at it now, I think there is an error in the assertion and it's actually creating duplicate share rows, but I can't tell for sure as it's not firing at all and granting access to the FA - have you tried looking at debug logs? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm

Yes I have looked at debug logs. It seemed to be running correctly, but it's creating duplicate share rows and I'm not sure how to make it stop. When I update in prod, it doesn't seem to fire at all for existing team members either.

It seemed to be running correctly, but it's creating duplicate share rows - contradictory statement. Usually you want to delete existing shares, then insert. Add code that checks for dupes prior to insert.

You're right, I did contradict myself. I learned that Financial Services uses Financial Account Role to share the Financial Accounts, so I updated my class to create Role records vs Share records, but it's still not working. Any help is appreciated!
